# TypeError: expressJwt is not a function

Tags: java, node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I'm trying to write middleware for user authorization in my app. I use this function to check if a route requires being sign in.
The code is as follows:

```
const { expressJwt } = require('express-jwt'); 

exports.requireSignin = expressJwt({
secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
algorithms: ["HS256"],
userProperty: "auth",});
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expressJwt is not a function at Object.<anonymous> (path to the file)\
```

What could be the problem? None of the other answers seem to be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the curly brackets

```
const { expressJwt } = require('express-jwt');
      ^            ^
```

you are trying to do *object destructuring*, which looks for a field named `expressJwt` in the object exported by `express-jwt` module. But according to the error message that object doesn't have such field.

As per [`express-jwt`'s documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt#usage), you don't need destructuring but to simply assign the exported object into a variable, so try the following form (without curly brackets):

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
```

Answer (score 14):

**2023 UPDATE**

With version greater than 7.x, use this as doc said (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) :

```
const { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");
```

Then you can use `jwt`:

```
jwt({
  secret: "shhhhhhared-secret",
  audience: "http://myapi/protected",
  issuer: "http://issuer",
  algorithms: ["HS256"],
});
```

Answer (score 4):

this work for me without high severity vulnerability caused by low version:

1. `npm uninstall express-jwt`
2. `npm install express-jwt@6.1.0`

Answer (score 2):

```
const { expressjwt: expressjwt } = require('express-jwt');
```

**OR**

```
const { expressjwt } = require('express-jwt');
```

Try lowercase this worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

Reference to the [readme](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt).

If I am not mistaken the right function is named jwt

```
//const { expressJwt } = require('express-jwt');

//use this 
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the possible solution found on multiple programming forums, but nothing worked, so I just downgrade my `express-jwt` version to `5.3.1` and it start working perfectly, so it means error is in new update, just uninstall current version with `npm uninstall express-jwt` and install again `npm I express-jwt@5.3.1`, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation worked for me:

```
var { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");

var jwtCheck = jwt({
      secret: jwks.expressJwtSecret({
          cache: true,
          ...more stuff
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an algorithm in the expressJwt object, add it next to the secret, separated by `,` and use cypher such as RS256. It happened to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const { expressjwt: ejwt } = require("express-jwt");
```

This worked for me, it should be `expressjwt` not `expressJwt` as documentation state.