# error using expressjwt : expressjwt is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, mongoose, express-jwt

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt')


function authJwt(){
    const secret= process.env.secret;
    return expressJwt({
        secret,
        algorithms: ['HS256']
    })
}

module.exports = authJwt;
```

i tried replacing expressJwt with {expressJwt},{expressjwt:expressJwt} and other solution given earlier. I also tried a version older than 7 but it also didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: expressJwt is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63661915/typeerror-expressjwt-is-not-a-function)

Comment: No i already tried and after that i posted this question again for more solution or is their any alternative for express-jwt